# How can I "generically" select worksheets from a script

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a script for a workbook that is to be used by multiple departments. The button click imports a weekly report to a master data worksheet, creates a new sheet/Tab, asks what to name that new worksheet (Which will be the week date the report references.), place an MS Query table onto the new sheet, filtered from the master, clears the master sheet and prepares the work book to repeat the same thing when the next weekly report gets added (...and is all working at the moment.).  The next time someone updates the workbook, it will the button click to again use the same script to add yet another worksheet for the new week and so on, but, since I started from recorded macros to writing the rest of what I need, everything in the script is referencing the first new worksheet by worksheet name, Like this example:

```
Application.Goto Reference:="W11_9_2020"
    Sheets("W11_9_2020").Select    
    Range("A1").Select
```

Here (Above) I would like this to be a generic reference to the latest sheet in the script, not the exact name so it is reusable the next x amount of times the workbook gets updated.

The next time someone updates this, it will still add a new sheet, but once it gets to the part where the query table is created and the new sheet is formatted, data added, blah blah, it's just going to repopulate the first sheet again since it used that sheet name in the script (Or error out).

I tried using:

```
Set Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) = wsDest1

    wsDest1.Range("I1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Week"
    wsDest1.Range("J1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Shipped"
    wsDest1.Range("K1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total On Time"
    wsDest1.Range("L1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Late"
    wsDest1.Range("L2").Select
```

..in the hopes of generically using a reference to the latest added worksheet (Which is always "Add after") but doing that brings an error stating that it is an illegal use of a procedure and highlights this line -->> Set Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) = wsDest1.

I guess in trying to write this for unlimited reuse, I would like the sheet references to be variables or something so it always references the latest added sheet before the button click would add another and repeat/rerun the same script for any given new update.

Is there another way to generically(?) identify the latest sheet/tab in the body of the script without the exact sheet name being identified?

Comment: Did you mean to use `Set wsDest1 = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) `?

Comment: Keep in mind this will just give you the last sheet in the collection, which is not necessarily the most recent one added, since the sheets can be rearranged after they are added.

Comment: Also, there is no need to use `Select` and all it does is slow it down... instead use: `wsDest1.Range("I1").FormulaR1C1 = "Week"` or better yet just `wsDest1.Range("I1").Formula = "Week"` or since it's not really a formula, just `wsDest1.Range("I1") = "Week"`

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the method to add a new worksheet also returns a reference to that worksheet. So, create the reference when you create the worksheet, and then refer to it later.

```
Sub AddSheet()
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    
    'Get the sheet name, however you're currently doing it
    sheetName = "NewSheet"
    
    Set wsNew = Worksheets.Add()
    wsNew.Name = sheetName
    
    'Do the rest of the stuff
    wsNew.Range("A1").Value = "Hello"
End Sub
```